# How to create a cmd line app from a node file

Tags: node.js

I have the following module in an npm package that I would somehow like to start and keep alive until a stop command is issued.  It is a fake ldap server that uses ldapjs:

```
const ldapjs = require('ldapjs');
var server;

const start = (config, data, cb) => {
  baseDN = config.baseDN;
  db = data;

  if(server) {
    if(typeof cb === 'function') {
      return cb();
    }

    return;
  }

  server = ldap.createServer();

  // rest of code

  server.listen(config.port, () => {
    if (typeof cb === 'function') {
      return cb();
    }
  });
};

const close = (next) => {
  if (server) {
    server.close();
  }

  server = null;

  if (typeof next === 'function') {
    return next();
  }

  return;
};

module.exports = {
  start: start,
  close: close
};
```

How can I make an executable that I call this from the cmd line?  I need the process to run indefinitely and I have limitations where I work as to what I can install.  I cannot install forever for example.

Also what is the best way to export this?  Should I use npm's bin section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of these:

Forever - https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

> forever start app.js
>
> forever list
>
> forever stop app.js

Commander - https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

> mycli -options

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the exporting, but compiling and running a node file from the command line is very easy.

Suppose your file is called `myFile.js`. If you're within the same directory that the file is in, simply run `$node myFile.js` and it should execute.